# How to clear form submission data

Tags: django, forms, post

I have a form submission in a page done with POST request.
There is no separate page for form itself.

When a user submits form and refreshes the page, the form data in the browser is not getting clear and thus asks "Confirm form submission" using an dialog box.

How to remove this?

I am using django for form submission and currently not using any Async submission (JavaScript) here.

Comment: I think this is solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510243/

Comment: well, that explains partially. If there was an error in form submission and the form still does not clear. how to avoid such dialogs from server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its cleaner to redirect to the same page after the form is complete.
This way you use a fresh GET request without any problems when reloading the url.

```
if method.POST:
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
        ...
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        ...
        ...
        form = ABCForm()
        return render_to_response(request, context={'form':form}, RequestContext)
```

Here `ABCForm` is your django form name which you are passing in context for displaying in django template