# PHP or JQUERY - Clear form fields after a successful submission

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I tried to empty the form fields after a successful form submission, however, it only seems like it is possible via jQuery and I cannot figure how.
I don't want to use .click() or .submit() e.g. `$("#signuBbtn").click()` in order to clear the input fields because it will always clear the form fields.

I want to clear the form fields **only when the form is successfully submitted and the posted data is inserted in MySQL.**

If i cannot clear the form fields via PHP, how do I call JQuery function that **clears the form fields**?

**register.php**

```
<?php
    if(!$formValidationError) {
        //code for clearing the input field PHP code
        //OR
        //calls JQuery form clearing function which is clearInput()
    }
?>
```

**script.js**

```
    function clearInput() {
        $("#email, #username, #password").each( function() {
           $(this).val('');
        });
    }
```

To add more info, I don't want to redirect or refresh the page. Also, in the **register.php**, I just want to know how to call `clearInput()` from the external js file which is **script.js**. OR I just want to know how to use php methods in order to clear the input fields.

Comment: why not do a regular form request and have php redirect back to the page? otherwise I need more code on how you're calling `clearInput()` right now

Comment: `$('#form_id').trigger("reset");`

Comment: just use jquery reset function
    $('#formId').reset()

Comment: @iam-decoder I don't want to redirect or refresh the page. I don't know how to call clearInput() from my register.php that's why I put up this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear the form field after successful submission of php form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510243/clear-the-form-field-after-successful-submission-of-php-form)

Comment: if you don't want to refresh the page, you have to submit the form with ajax and check the result of the submission to clear the form if you don't have error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Quick fix for your situation.

To call a js function from php:

```
<?php
    if(!$formValidationError) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
            '$(function(){ clearInput(); })',
        '</script>';
    }
?>
```

or

```
<?php
    if(!$formValidationError) {
?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){ clearInput(); })
    </script>

<?php } ?>
```

Echo the js script after jQuery librairy script tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `reset()` function on the form element.

```
<form id="form">
    .........
    ........
</form>
```

jQuery code:

```
$("#form")[0].reset()
// or
$("#form").get(0).reset()
```

Comment: thank yout but I want to use `reset()` function **ONLY when sign up form is SUCCESSFULLY submitted**. your code will just reset the whole form field  whether it is successfully submitted or not

Comment: Well, do you have a validation function? You need to mention this code only if function returns true.

Comment: you mean the form validation? I have multiple sets of `if statements` for form validation in `register.php`. But I just don't know how to clear the form fields after the validation and submission in php

Answer (score 0):

Try this to clear all type of input fields

```
$(':input','#myform')
.not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
.val('')
.removeAttr('checked')
.removeAttr('selected');
```

Comment: thank you but I wasn't asking how to clear the form. I was asking how to clear the form **ONLY AFTER the successful form submission**.

Comment: write this in button click event

Comment: as I have mentioned in my question, I don't want to use `button click event` because it will clear the form fields every time (even when the form data is not inserted into MySQL or fails form validation).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can clear the form fields with php when you have successfully inserted the values in the database with `$_POST = array();` this will clear the form data

take a look for example

```
<?php


// your validation here

try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstName,lastName,title,email,userPassword,categoryID,provinceID,cityID,planID) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    if ($stmt->execute(array(
        $firstname,
        $lastname,
        $title,
        $email,
        $hash,
        $category,
        $province,
        $city,
        $plan
    ))) {


        echo "Form submitted";

        $_POST = array(); //clear input fields
    } else {

        echo "form not submitted";
    }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {


    error_log($e->getMessage());
}


?>
```

Comment: how do I do this without PDO? I'm using Mysqli

Comment: all you need is the `$_POST = array();` when you print your success message even if you using mysqli. after you have successfully inserted to the database you add that line.