# Resetting form input after submit and/or redirect

Tags: php, forms, email, redirect, submit

I have setup a contact form which is working nicely but I encountered two issues Im not able to solve.

First, I wonder if theres a good way to clear data which have been input by users in the form, for example after submit I want name/mail/message-fields to be cleared.

But the bigger problem is that with every submit or refresh the same info gets emailed and Ive read up on this and so far I only found the redirect way of solving this. To redirect to an other page after email sent (thankyou.php etc). If this is the ONLY way to solve this, well then the first issue is not a problem since I have to do this obviously. If so, how do I implement this?

Im trying to use `if(!$mail->Send()) {
    header("Location: http://www.example.com");
    exit;
    }`

but im not able to get it to work, the page stays on same page but the form disappears. Mail still sent though.

In a perfect world, I would like to stay on same page, clear the fields and not be able to resend same data with refresh - but it seems like that is not possible?

If it isnt, here is my code - where should I use the header-redirect?

**UPDATE**

I managed to do it! This is in Wordpress btw.

HTML/contact.php:

```
<form id="contact-form" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;"> <!--This calls submitForm(); and stops the form of doing anything else when submitted, prevents reloading-->
        <div class="contact-input">
          <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-input">
          <input type="email" id="mail" placeholder="Your mail" required>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-input">
          <textarea id="message" placeholder="Your message" rows="10" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Send"><span id="status"></span>
      </form>
```

JavaScript/contactform.js:

```
    function _(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id); //makes _ a shortcode for document.getElementById(id)
}

    function submitForm() {
            _("submitButton").disabled = true; //User cant click submit many times and resend form data, after first click its disabled.
            _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait...'; //Gives span value and the user an indication of that data is being processed.
            var formdata = new FormData(); // Creates variable that fetches they key value pair of id and value of  the form inputs.
            formdata.append( "name", _("name").value );
            formdata.append( "mail", _("mail").value );
            formdata.append( "message", _("message").value );
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); // creating an ajax variable which is a XMLHttpRequest, opens it/fires it by posting the formdata to parser.php
            ajax.open( "POST", "parser.php" );
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function() { //when ready do this function
                if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) { //when data is finished processing by php and data is returned by php to this ajax object(XMLHttpRequest)
                    if(ajax.responseText == "success") {
                    _("contact-form").innerHTML = '<h2>Thanks for contacting me '+_("name").value+' I will get back to you as soon as possible.</h2>'
                } else {
                _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                _("submitButton").disabled = false; 
                clearForm();
                } 
            }
        }
        ajax.send( formdata );
    }
```

PHP / parser.php: (included_once in functions.php)

```
    <?php
if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['mail']) && isset($_POST['message']) ) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $message = nl2br($_POST['message']);
    $to = "kontakt@emcolsson.se";
    $from = $mail;
    $subject = 'Contact form message';
    $message = '<b>Name:</b> '.$name.' <br><b>Email:</b> '.$mail.' <p>'.$message.'</p>';
    $headers = "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.";
    }
}
?>
```

JavaScript/clearform.js

```
function clearForm()
{
    document.getElementById("name").value=""; //don't forget to set the textbox ID
    document.getElementById("mail").value=""; //don't forget to set the textbox ID
    document.getElementById("message").value=""; //don't forget to set the textbox ID
}
```

Now, the only problem is that when sent/submitted, the page copies itself and I have the page as it were before + another full page (with header, menu, footer) beneath it. Why is this?
Except that now mail is sent, fomr is cleared and refresh/new push on submit-button doesnt send another copy of the form as an mail - awesome!

Img: [2x header and footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPj8H.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, what you want is essentially the behavior of an ajax form - submission, validation, server delivery, and clearing of the form - without a page reload, correct?

Comment: hi! you were quick :) - well, yeah, but the page reloading or not only matters if that means that it sends the form data again and in this case an duplicate email. can I solve it all with ajax? never used that before but I want to learn it if so!

Comment: Yes, AJAX is a good solution for all of your problems.

I still suggest what I noted below, though, to wrap your submission code in an if(isset($_POST['submit']) conditional.

Comment: I actually managed to do it! Ill update the post, because there is still some questions!

Comment: I believe that wordpress has its own ajax hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Good work learning the fundamentals of AJAX!

In terms of handling ajax in wordpress specifically, there are some [wordpress hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side) for this:

[This article](http://solislab.com/blog/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/) does a good job overviewing some of the fixes you will need to fine-tune this.

The key to making your form work the wordpress way is to use the built in wordpress hooks, but they also suggest the following:

Passing your ajax request to admin-ajax.php.

Use jQuery to handle form submission.

Applying a nonce field to protect the form processor script (you should do this no matter what).

---

Don't forget to read up on [the basics of PHP forms](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-post.html).

The simplest thing to prevent form resubmission is to wrap your form validation code in a `if(isset($_POST['submit'])` condition.

In terms of emptying the fields, you can do what the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510243/clear-the-form-field-after-successful-submission-of-php-form) suggests: reset your `$_POST` variable after you've handled the form, or simply not echo out the `$_POST` data in your input values.

The questions to ask regarding the use of AJAX are the following:

Can you set up a separate file on your system to handle the php processing - but none of the html or javascript - of this form?

Do you have access to a library such as jQuery to smooth the transition into using XHR?

If so, you can make this form an ajax form that posts its data to your separate php file. That will ensure that only the javascript event you have chosen to trigger the form submission will run the php code. Plus it will give you all the fun animation stuff that javascript can handle and your no page reload goodness.

Comment: Ok today I am gonna solve this no matter how long time it takes. Where do I start with this? Do you have any good examples I can look at - or should I just google AJAX forms and try to imitate this til it works?

Answer (score 0):

you have a couple options.  You can clear fields by specific id.  I'm using a button to demonstrate, but you can use your callback function.  Run this code in a fiddle if you like.

```
<input id="inputs" type="text" value="hello world">
<button onclick="emptyInputs()">Empty</button>

<script>
function emptyInputs(){
document.getElementById('inputs').value="";
}
<script>
```

You can also clear them by assigning a class to the inputs you want to clear.  You'd have to loop through all the inputs.. notice I'm clearing index [0]... you can loop and clear them all.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('inputs')[0].setAttribute("value", "");
```

You can also use Jquery to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Use:
function redirect($url, $status = 302) {
        header('Location: ' . str_replace(array('&', "\n", "\r"), array('&', '', ''), $url), true, $status);
        exit();
    }